# Character set in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I am using oracle 11G  with character set as utf8. I have a table which has japanese and chinese characters in it.

When I query the database using a simple JDBC program I am only getting question marks as the output.

Can some one please help me in that?

Comment: How are you viewing the output? When in doubt, log each character in the output as an integer, then compare against the Unicode code charts.

Comment: i took the string which is retrieved from DB and converted to a char array and got the numeric value of each character using the below function
Character.getNumericValue(char);

i am getting -1 as the numeric value for all the characters. all the characters are question marks only.

Comment: That's not how you should be getting them - that's trying to treat them as digits. Use `charAt` and just cast to an int.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you are saying that

```
SELECT value
  FROM v$nls_parameters
 WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'
```

returns `UTF8`?  That's pretty unusual particularly in 11g-- it would be much more common to see a value of `AL32UTF8` which is a more recent version of the Unicode standard.

What happens when you look at the data that is actually stored in the database?  If you run the same query that you're running via JDBC against the database directly but call the `DUMP` function instead of just selecting the column, what is the output?

```
SELECT DUMP( column_name, 1016 ) 
  FROM table_name
 WHERE some_key = some_value
```

Are you using the thin Oracle JDBC driver?  Or are you using the OCI JDBC driver?  Or are you using the Oracle ODBC driver and the JDBC-ODBC bridge as your tags imply?  The latter would be exceptionally unusual in this day and age-- there is really no reason to ever use the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver if the database platform provides a native JDBC driver.

Is the `NLS_LANG` set on the client?

Comment: Justin cave, it is UTF8 only. not AL32UTF8. and for the second query it returns Typ=1 Len=26 CharacterSet=UTF8: 6d,43,49,43,4f,e6,97,a5,e6,9c,ac,e3,81,b8,e3,82,88,e3,81,86,e3,81,93,e3,81,9d. i am using thin oracle driver

Comment: @user1029292 - OK.  And that is supposed to represent the string "mCICO" followed by 7 3-byte characters, right?  That implies that the data is being stored correctly.  What Oracle driver are you using?  The thin JDBC driver?  The OCI JDBC driver?  The ODBC driver with the JDBC=ODBC bridge?  Something else?

Comment: its thin JDBC driver. thats what i am using now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved
Eclipse > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding to UTF-8
Thanks everyone.